# expected unqualified-i before '.' token - C struct

Tags: c, struct

I'm coding a Pokemon battle and am using structs to define moves and individual Pokemon. However, each line where I try to initialize one of the struct variables throws the above error and I can't see anything wrong with the syntax in terms of missing semicolons etc. Any light to be shed would be greatly appreciated. Here's a snippet:

```
typedef struct move {
    string name;
    int power;
    int accuracy;
    string type;
} qik_attack, pin_missle, shadow_ball, thunder, psychic,swift, earthquake, ice_beam;

qik_attack.name = "QUICK ATK";
qik_attack.power = 40;
qik_attack.accuracy=100;
qik_attack.type = "normal";
```

Comment: `typedef` defines a type. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `string name` is not C. I think you want `char * name`.

Comment: Remove that `typedef` and try again.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: maybe `string` is a typedef for `char*`, or maybe this code is actually the dreaded "C/C++"!

Comment: Removing typedef gives the error "qik_attack does not name a type"

Comment: Maybe you're trying to assign a value to variable outside function.

Comment: @user2988064 Where are you placing the assignment code?

Comment: This is all done before main() but putting the assignments inside main() changes nothing.

Comment: @user2988064 No, it will change something.

Comment: Remove `typedef` AND move assignment inside function

Comment: @user2988064 What is the definition of `string`?

Comment: It did indeed. Now I get "incompatible types in assignment of 'main()::lambda())' to 'move[4]'". I don't even know what a lambda is.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
typedef struct move {
    ...
} qik_attack
```

defines `qik_attack` as a type name.

But in

```
qik_attack.name = "QUICK ATK";
```

you are using `qik_attack` as a variable.

So just remove that `typedef` and try again.

Of course, you should put those assignments in a function.

Answer (score 2):

As others said don't use `typedef` if you don't (yet) understand what that does.

```
struct move {
    string name;
    int power;
    int accuracy;
    string type;
};
```

declares the structure type without fuzz. Then a correct definition of such a structure with initialization looks like

```
struct move qik_attack = {
  .name = "QUICK ATK",
  .power = 40,
  .accuracy=100,
  .type = "normal",
};
```

All that supposing that you have defined `string` somewhere. (Or do you mix up C and C++ ?)

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct move {
    string name;
    int power;
    int accuracy;
    string type;
} qik_attack, pin_missle, shadow_ball, thunder, psychic,swift, earthquake, ice_beam;
```

Take a second to read what is going on here, you are defining type names for the
struct `move`, not instances of the struct `move`.

Just declare the type by itself, and instansiate the instances elsewhere in the program.

```
typedef struct move_t {
    string name;
    int power;
    int accuracy;
    string type;
} move_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   move_t qik_attack, pin_missle, shadow_ball, thunder, psychic,swift, earthquake, ice_beam;

   /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't assign a value to string or char[] in C. So for that you can go for strcpy or strncpy as well as you have typedef will create problem here

strcpy(qik_attack.name,"QUICK ATK");